# difference b/w (input) and (ionChange) event - ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to call web service after 10 characters, but i noticed that when i used `(input)="onInput()"` it called twice don't know why.

After few search i change it to `ionChange="onInput()"` it's working and fine.
My question is:

> 1: Difference b/w these two events? 
>   2: Is that fine to used `event.stopPropagation()` in ionic-3 to prevent twice call.

html:

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]='time' 
   (ionChange)='onInput($event)'>
</ion-input>
```

home.ts

```
onInput() {
   ## call service
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ionChange` is an Angular EventEmitter that is used by Ionic to handle input changes in most the custom components .It is defined in [BaseInput.ts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/d0cad6b31ebe4eb1d644d06644ec1fabf683e9d1/src/util/base-input.ts) which is extended by [input.ts](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/d0cad6b31ebe4eb1d644d06644ec1fabf683e9d1/src/components/input/input.ts),

```
@Output() ionChange: EventEmitter<BaseInput<T>> = new EventEmitter<BaseInput<T>>(); 
//...
_fireIonChange() {
    if (this._init) {
      this._debouncer.debounce(() => {
        assert(NgZone.isInAngularZone(), 'IonChange: should be zoned');
        this.ionChange.emit(this._inputChangeEvent());
        this._initModel = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

`input` is just the DOM [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) that can be used with Ionic elements as well as basic html input elements.

`ionChange`, when compared to `input` event, has a number of checks in place before it emits which could be preventing it to fire multiple times on value change.

> Is that fine to used event.stopPropagation() in ionic-3 to prevent twice call.

Yes, you can pass any parameter including html `$event` and call its functions.